# I have an issue to display nested json file in side-nav

Tags: html, json, angular, angular-material

I have an issue to display my nested json to mat-side-nav

My json file department:

```
{departmentID: 15;                             
 departmentName: Site;
 listOfDepartment: Department []}
```

so I have 5 sublevels, same type as global Department

**My issue:** I can display only 2-level of this tree, not more

I'll be very appreciative of any help...
my code below in HTML

```html
<mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'" [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">

    <mat-toolbar *ngIf="department!==undefined" color="accent">{{department.departmentName}}</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="checkbox" (change)="onLoadTree($event)">Active1 </mat-checkbox>        
        <ng-template #recursiveList let-department>
            <mat-nav-list *ngFor="let dep of department.listOfDepartments" (click)="toggleMenu(dep.departmentId)" routerLink="/list" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a mat-list-item *ngIf="dep" routerLink="/list" routerLinkActive="active">
                    {{dep.departmentName}}
                    <mat-icon *ngIf="!showMenu(dep.departmentId)">chevron_right</mat-icon>
                    <mat-icon *ngIf="showMenu(dep.departmentId)">expand_more</mat-icon>
                </a>
                <div *ngIf="dep.listOfDepartments.length">                     
                    <mat-nav-list *ngIf="showMenu(dep.departmentId)" class="submenu">
                        <a ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: dep}"> 
                    </a>
                    </mat-nav-list>
                </div>
            </mat-nav-list>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: department}"></ng-container>
    </div>

</mat-sidenav>
```

Comment: I checked my recursion it works perfectly, what I see for now I have wrong code for show and hide subdepartments  `showMenu(depId: number): boolean {    
    return depId === this.curDepId;
  }

  toggleMenu(depId: number) {
    if (this.curDepId === depId) {
      this.curDepId = 0;
      
      console.log('close')
    }
    else {
      this.curDepId = depId;
      console.log('open')
    }
    
  }`  how can I change this code properly?  THX!

Comment: So I need multilevel Vertical Menu with Toggle and collapse events....